# Reactjs Hook onChange with react-datepicker, invalid time value error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker

im new to react hooks and i tried to convert react-datepicker from class to function with hooks.
The problem is when i trigger the onChange will show (RangeError: Invalid time value), but default "selected" start date is rendering fine. Can this be done with hooks?

```
 import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
 import Datepicker from 'react-datepicker';

 const Example = () => {

 const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

 const handleChange = date => {
   setStartDate({ startDate: date });
  }

 return (
   <Fragment>
    <Datepicker
     selected={startDate}
     onChange={handleChange}
    />
   </Fragment>
 )
}

export default Example;
```

i expect the startDate state is changed without "RangeError: Invalid time value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not inserting a date into the state but an object rather.

change:

```
setStartDate({ startDate: date });
```

to:

```
setStartDate(date);
```

Comment: ouch, thank you very much, that does solve my problem.

Comment: @FunkeyFlo then how to show date on another component. i am using {date} to show date in another component. but it's give me error. "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Thu Apr 30 2020 13:43:41 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Answer (score 0):

I have used it in my project as reusable component

```
    return (
      <DatePicker
        fixedHeight
        showFullMonthYearPicker
        showDisabledMonthNavigation
        selected={selectedDate}
        value={valueDate}
        onChange={(day) => onChange && onChange(day, flag)}
        className="react-datepicker__input-container-days"
      />
    );
  };
```

This is where im calling my component

```
{renderDateDay({       
          flag: 0,
                                valueDate: manuFucturedValue.day,
                                selectedDate:
                                  (manuFucturedValue.day &&
                                    new Date(manuFucturedValue.day)) ||
                                  null,
                                onChange: (day) =>
                                  handleDateOnchange(day, "day", 0),
```